# Not able to add a video to a Medium story

Tags: video, embed

I was writing a blog about the chatbot I made. I pasted the URL of my video which is uploaded on Vimeo and then pressed Enter. The video doesn't load and this is the error I get:

> cdn.embedly refused to connect

I think it is an issue with Medium not being able to connect to Embedly's API but still I want to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Go to the Vimeo video you want to embed and find the Share button
> 2. Copy the link.
> 3. Paste the link into your Medium article and hit Enter.
>
> You’re all done! The Vimeo video embed should automatically load into
> your article within a few seconds.

From https://medium.com/embeds/embed-a-video-on-medium-using-vimeo-bf35c30f33af